# Joomla - Get the specific Menu's Details / Parameter's

Tags: joomla, parameters, menu

I have a menu with the alias called "cooking-baking". I want to get the parameters of that menu. Below is the code am currently using.

```
$app    = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu   = $app->getMenu();
$menu   = $menu->getItems('menutype', 'cooking-baking');
```

Please do help me if you have any idea. I' am really stuck.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close, but use alias as filtering criteria. Menu type is a group of menu items (main menu, side menu etc) that you defined in Menu Manager in Administration.
Note: Third parameter determines if to return first matched item.

```
$app      = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu     = $app->getMenu();
$menuItem = $menu->getItems('alias', 'cooking-baking', true);
```

or multiple attributes:

```
$menuItem = $menu->getItems(array('alias', 'menutype'), array('cooking-baking', 'mainmenu'), true);
```

see [JMenu::getItems documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/JMenu%3a%3agetItems/11.1)

$menuItem is an object containing data (id, menutype, title, alias etc.). To get paremeters, access `$menuItem->params` which is a [JRegistry object](http://docs.joomla.org/JRegistry%3a%3aget/11.1).

So for example to get `show_intro` paremeter of that menu item, use

```
$show_intro = $menuItem->params->get('show_intro', $default = null);
```